# Is it wrong just to move repository from 1.5 server to 1.7 server?

Tags: svn, svn-repository

We have SVN repository under Subversion 1.5 server.
I need to move this repository to another Subversion 1.7 server.

As far as I understand there are 3 ways:

- Just move repository to new server.
- Create dump of a SVN 1.5 repository and import the dump to new 1.7 server with the so-called [dump-load cycle](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#dumpload).

  `svnadmin dump`

  `svnadmin load`
- Move repository to new server and then upgrade it to the latest supported schema version:

  `svnadmin upgrade`

**Is it wrong just to move folder of my repository to the new 1.7 server from 1.5 server?

Could there be any problems? If yes - what problems?**

Comment: 1. http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#dumpload 2. http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.6.html#repos-upgrades

Comment: So I need either import dump or upgrade repository. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just moving the repository *will work*, but it won't give you the optimal result. Subversion 1.6 introduced some repository optimizations that you will miss when you don't perform the dump/load cycle.

```
svnadmin upgrade <REPOSITORY>
```

Will enable future revisions to store the new in 1.6 information, but it will not upgrade the old revisions. But it will at least work better/the same than/as sticking with a 1.5 repository.

(1.7 didn't introduce a new format, so you are upgrading the format to 1.6 compatible)

New in 1.6 format:

- representation sharing (disk usage improvement)
- store whether a node is a file or directory per log item (svn log improvement)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the most experienced subversion admin, but I think dump/load to the new server would be a pretty painless and straight forward task.  It gets my vote.